# NetSuite - Update Transaction via REST API

Tags: netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

I'm very new to NetSuite and have a lot to learn. Currently I'm able to use use the REST API to get customers, upsert customers, query, etc. However, I am completely confused why I am not able to do the same with the 'transaction' table and why it's not showing in the API Browser. Is this possible and I'm overlooking something?

I expected an endpoint similar to https://xxxxx.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/transaction/293

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Transaction" does not show in the API Browser, but many transaction types do show.  For example:

- [Sales Order](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2023.1/index.html#tag-salesOrder)
- [Purchase Order](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2023.1/index.html#tag-purchaseOrder)
- [Invoice](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2023.1/index.html#tag-invoice)

And others.  You can use these to perform your desired operations on various transactions.

Comment: Ok makes sense - thank you!